# Azure "Availability Set" doesn´t show in other VMs configuration

Tags: azure, high-availability, azure-virtual-machine

We´ve created a number of VMs on Azure and want to group those together into a "Frontend" availability set.

So, we created a availability set in the config of the 1st VM:
[image]

Unfortunately, on the other VMs it doesn´t show up in the dropdown.
[image]
Are we missing something? How can we add the other Servers to the set?

Comment: If you created the VMs in different Regions then you won't be able to add them to the same Availability Set.

Comment: Hey Simon, the VMs are in the same region...

Comment: Might be related to the CloudService Config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that all VMs created are in the same cloud service if you want them to be part of the same Availability set. Once they are, you will be able to view the Availability set when you try to add other VMs.